# How to make the thickness of the line constant?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

I created this code based on a previous post, with some modifications to plot a line with a 30-degree slash. It partially works, but the thickness of the slash varies from line to line. How can I make it a constant thickness?

Additionally, I would appreciate your help with modifying the label position so that it is placed near the line without crossing it. The label is always short, such as `M1x`. Should I create a new post for this issue?

```
ClearAll[myLines]
myLines[{a1_, a2_}, color_ : Black, label_] := 
 Block[{d, l, s, t, midpoint, offset, slash, angle},
  d = a2 - a1;
  l = Norm[d];
  midpoint = (a1 + a2)/2;
  offset = {0.2, 0.2};
  angle = 
   Which [d[[1]] != 0, ArcTan[d[[2]]/d[[1]]], 
    d[[1]] == 0 && d[[2]] > 0, \[Pi]/2, 
    d[[1]] == 0 && d[[2]] < 0, - (\[Pi]/2)];
  slash = 
   Graphics[{Directive[Red, Thickness[0.1], CapForm["Round"]], 
     GeometricTransformation[Line[{{-0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0}}], 
      RotationTransform[30 Degree + angle, {0, 0}]]}];
  {Directive[color, Thickness[0.01], CapForm["Round"]], 
   Line[{a1, a2}], color, 
   Text[Style[label, 20, Bold], midpoint + offset], 
   Inset[slash, midpoint, {0, 0}, Scaled[{1/10, 1/10}]]}]
(*Define some points for the lines*)
p1 = {3, 1};
p2 = {5, 2};
p3 = {5, 5};
(*Draw two example lines*)
{Graphics[myLines[{p1, p2}, "My Line Label"], ImageSize -> 300], 
 Graphics[myLines[{p1, p3}, "My Line Label"], ImageSize -> 300]}
```

[image]

Comment: It's `RotationTransform` that causes the issue with the thickness, right?

Comment: @bmf I think so but I need to rotate it 30 degree.

Comment: `AbsoluteThickness[5]` work.

Comment: In addition to @cvgmt for the position of the label, does this cover what you want? `Text[Style[label, 20, Bold], -2 angle + midpoint + offset]` In these two examples it works nicely I think

Comment: @bmf `AbsoluteThickness` works well but the label you suggested is placed too far from the mid point.